# System Identification in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

In Matlab I have created a single-output multiple-input fitted model as an idpoly object. This is by using the system identification toolbox and the model is a Box-Jenkins or Transfer Function model. I now want to see what the model does if I put in different inputs (same amount) and no output (model should estimate the output given the input). Yet I did not find a method in Matlab that can do so.

Is there any way I can use an idpoly object (model) in Matlab and use only input to obtain an output? I have tried the command "sim" but it does not do the job.

Comment: what is wrong with sim?

Comment: Lets assume I fitted the model using the system identification UI. It generates a high fit. Yet if I use "sim(model,data)" (same model, same data) I get a very different fit.

Comment: I think it got something to do with the initial condition.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command "forecast" and specify the input values for the forecast.